# install pydev without rights to eclipse installation

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

My apologies if this has already been asked and answered.  I don't know enough about eclipse & pydev setup to know what to search for.

I'd like to use pydev, but can't modify the existing installation of eclipse.  Do I need to install my own eclipse so that I can then install pydev into it, or is there a way to install pydev off to the side such that I can then use it with the existing eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was multiple installations: eclipse is not that big (~250mb I think), but it's quite slow, so you'll want to have as little plugins as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked quite nicely for me when I was using Pydev with Eclipse as a non-privileged user on a shared computer was to install Eclipse+Pydev on a flash drive. You have the added advantage of being able to work from any computer while having your usual settings.